# how to implement a Model for these needs

Tags: django

say I have the following model:

```
Class Classroom(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=128)
```

Initially, I want this `Classroom` to be available to be occupied on every weekend of the year(both on Saturday and Sunday). A person, can then come and occupy/rent the `classroom` for a certain day. For example, Mr. Foo sees that it is available and wants to occupy it this Satuday, on 27th of September. What is a solution(or the best one) to implement this logic?

What is the approach? should I create another table and which? What type of fields should I add?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    day = models.DateField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    classroom = models.ManyToManyField(Classroom, related_name='appointments')
```

EDIT:

Availability should be rather placed in the middle table between Classroom and Appointment and the ManyToManyField should have `through=tablename` where tablename is the name of this table.

EDIT:

Actually I wanted to have a supper, but this question is now more important than my appetite :)

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=128)

class WeekendDay(models.MOdel): # this was before Appointment
    day = models.DateField()
    classroom = models.ManyToManyField(Classroom, through="Appointment")

class Appointment(models.Model)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    weekend_day = models.ForeignKey(WeekendDay, related_name='appointments_per_day')
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, related_name='appointments_per_classroom')
```

I think something like this should work, if you have many classrooms, which are available on many days. Through the field `available` you can see or set the availability. If a classroom is booked let's say on next Saturday, then its value should be set to `False`. This should be the basic skeleton, you can extend the models according to your needs.

Comment: and so, with that M2M field, I have to populate Appointment with all the weekend days in a year (52 wknds in a year, so about ~104 entries in my Appointment).  Am I right? This is for your first solution...now I'm looking at the second one

Comment: The models after the second edit are important. That should work. You can populate WeekendDay with all Saturdays and Sundays, you could also extend the model with a ChoiceField with options ('Saturday', 'Sunday'), so it is user friendlier, better than just having the date. In the intermediate table you'll combine an Appointment (Classroom + WeekendDay).

Comment: great. valuable information. also looks simillar with what`s here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships